# Android Download Manager is duplicating existing files

Tags: android, android-file, android-download-manager

I am trying to download Audio files into one of the directories owned by the application using DownloadManager.
Here is my code:

```
    File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC), 
    audioName + ".mp3");

    if (file.exists()) {
        return;
    } else {

        DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                downloadUri);

        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
                DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                        | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE).setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(true).setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false)
                .setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(file));

        mgr.enqueue(request);
    }
```

The problem is that downloadManager is duplicating already downloaded audios, for exemple if I have an audio file named "test.mp3" I would find both "test.mp3" and "test1.mp3" in my application directory.

Am I doing something wrong?

Please keep in mind that I want to download files in the app directory and this is why I am using **setDestinationUri**

Comment: where are you populating this 'audioName ' variable? You need to check this

Comment: Where does `audioName` come from?

Comment: I am fetching audioName from a server using Volley, What I want is that if the audio name already exists, the file won't simply be downloaded.

Comment: can you please what value you are getting every time?

Comment: If i try to download a file named " test.mp3" many times I will get " test-1.mp3" "test-2.mp3" test-3.mp3" etc.... depending of the number of times I have called the code above. But what I want is when the file is already downloaded ( already exists in the directory), it won't be downloaded again. I hope this is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Up to date what I have realized is that the download manager rarely stops downloading and will keep doing so and appending values to the same file name. So I suggest going through your destination directory and deleting duplicate files. You can call this method onCreate.

```
     private void cleanUp()
        {
            String path = "PATH TO YOUR DOWNLOAD DIRECTORY/FOLDER NAME/";
            Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
            File directory = new File(path);
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
            {
                Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
                for(int j=1;j<files.length;j++)
                {
                    if(files[i].getName().contains("-"+String.valueOf(j)+".mp3")) // format according to how your download manager has renamed the file e.g "-"+String.valueOf(j)+".mp3" for fileName-1.mp3 or  String.valueOf(j)+".mp3" for fileName1.mp3
                    {
                        toast(files[i].getName());
                        files[i].delete();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```